# how to prevent zypper from install libreoffice on opensuse tumbleweed upgrade

Tags: linux, opensuse, zypper

I wanted to update the system with `zypper dup` command but Each time the command is executed, the zypper tries to install **libreoffice*** and some other apps, although I have already deleted that **libreoffice*** program and **patterns-office**!

I also run this command to check patterns: `zypper se --recommends libreoffice`
result is:

```
S | Name                        | Summary                              | Type
--+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------
  | OpenLP                      | Open source Church presentation an-> | package
  | gcin                        | Chinese input method server          | package
  | patterns-gnome-gnome_office | GNOME Office                         | package
  | patterns-kde-kde_office     | KDE Office                           | package
  | patterns-mate-mate_office   | MATE Office                          | package
  | patterns-office-office      | Office Software                      | package
  | patterns-xfce-xfce_office   | XFCE Office                          | package
```

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an option to avoid installing recommended packages :
`zypper dup --no-recommends`

From zypper dup --help :
`--no-recommends    Do not install recommended packages, only required ones.`